# Traefik: "No ACME certificate generation required for domains" in the logs while using the default cert

Tags: ssl, traefik, certbot, swarm, acme

I'm struggling with Let's Encrypt setup for my Docker Swarm.
Traefik is started this way in my stack's compose file:

```
    image: traefik:v2.2
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
      - 8080:8080
    command:
      - --api
      - --log.level=DEBUG
      - --providers.docker=true
      - --providers.docker.endpoint=unix:///var/run/docker.sock
      - --providers.docker.swarmMode=true
      - --providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false
      - --providers.docker.network=traefik-public
      - --entrypoints.http.address=:80
      - --entrypoints.https.address=:443

      - --certificatesResolvers.certbot=true
      - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.httpChallenge=true
      - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.httpChallenge.entrypoint=http
      - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.email=${EMAIL?Variable EMAIL not set}
      - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.storage=/certs/acme-v2.json
      - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

    ...networks, volumes...

    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1 # to avoid concurrency issues
      ...
      labels:
        - "traefik.docker.network=traefik-public"
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.my-domain.com`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http,https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.tls.certresolver=certbot"
        - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-auth"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:${HASHED_PASSWORD?Variable HASHED_PASSWORD not set}"
```

And I cannot get more than

```
level=debug msg="No ACME certificate generation required for domains [\"traefik.my-domain.com\"]." providerName=certbot.acme routerName=traefik@docker rule="Host(`traefik.my-domain.com`)"
```

I wonder why no ACME certificate is required while Firefox complains of getting the "TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT" (Chromium also btw).

I also tried:

- Without the staging server of let's encrypt
- With a DNS challenge as I hope to make it work with wildcard *.my-domain.com for dev purpose (which works manually with certbot).
- Setting a traefik.my-domain.com DNS zone (to remove the wildcard case from the problem)
- Changed the mode "replicated" of the deploy with global as suggested here [Traefik + Consul not generaitng SSL certificates in replicated mode, using TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903658/traefik-consul-not-generaitng-ssl-certificates-in-replicated-mode-using-traef)
- I'm presently looking for a way to handle certificates renewal with Certbot directly on my servers...

Answer (score 3):

I've had same issue, and it helped me to change the volume where acme.json is stored. I think it's because Traefik sees that **acme.json** is not empty, he simply doesn't ask for new cert.

So if you're using something like:

```
command:
...
  - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.storage=/certs/acme-v2.json
volumes:
  - "certs:/certs"
```

Try to use different volume:

```
command:
...
  - --certificatesResolvers.certbot.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme-v2.json
volumes:
  - "letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
```

Comment: I tried it multiple times without success but thanks for your insight. I would know that it may work now

Comment: I deleted the acme.json file (as it didn't have any content yet) and retried. Worked just fine this time. Good hint!

Answer (score 3):

For me it was the set **default (custom) Cert**, that was valid for the full domain, so traefik didn't request a specific acme/letsencrypt one, because it thought it already has one.

After disabling the custom default cert it worked instantly.

Comment: how did you disable it?

Comment: @DanielKatz I just renamed the configuration file `filename.yml` to something like `filename.yml.disabled` so traefik ignores it. 
_(assumed in this file only the default certificate option is set)_